# height() of header element in AngularJS returns "null"

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm trying to dynamically size a Google Map and for that I think I need to find the height of the header.

I was hoping for something like this to work:

```
$scope.init = function() {
    $log.info("init");

    var header = angular.element('#header');
    console.log(header);
    console.log(header.height());

    var height = $window.innerHeight - header.height(); 
    angular.element("#photo-map .angular-google-map-container").height(height);
};


<body data-ng-controller="MainCtrl" data-ng-cloak="true" data-ng-init="init()">...</body>
```

However, while header gets found the `header.height()` returns `null`, likely due to it not being loaded yet.

I've also tried `window.on("load", ...)`, `window.onload`, `$document.ready()` and some other jQuery-esque approaches too.

If, however, I do a flat-out timeout then it works, so I really just haven't found the right event to tie it to.

Any ideas which is the right event?

---

Tried with $timeout:

```
$scope.init = function() {
    $timeout(function() {
        $log.info("header height", $('#header').height(), $('#header'));
    });
};
```

Output:

```
header height null [context: document, selector: "#header", jquery: "2.1.1", constructor: function, toArray: function…]
```

Comment: use a directive so the code runs when element exists

Comment: `#header` element exists and is found. It's nothing fancy, just a Bootstrap `nav`.

Answer (score 0):

Try $timeout - $timeout runs after the render phase:

```
$scope.init = function() {
    $log.info("init");

    $timeout(function() {
       var header = angular.element('#header');
       console.log(header);
       console.log(header.height());

       var height = $window.innerHeight - header.height(); 
       angular.element("#photo-map .angular-google-map-container").height(height);
    });
};
```